# Embed Paper.js in Python

Tags: python, webserver, embed, paperjs

I am building a Server application in Python language, but because I need to work with SVG graphics (specifically, I need the function of subtracting SVG Path Objects from one and another), I thought about embedding Paper.js, which delivers the functionality into Python, but my question is, is this possible? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using a Python SVG library ([one of them](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=python+svg+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)) ; and if you need complex shape operations you can use [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php), it's nice and very powerful (and usable with Python).